# Jailbreaking an iPod touch 2G: Is it possible with OS 3.1.1

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, ios

I own an iPod touch 2G and would like to jailbreak it so that i can develop with something other than objective-c. However the information on the "iphone dev-team" blog seems unclear. Is it at all possible?

**I understand that SuperUser does not endorse these activities, and if anyone attempts this they risk bricking their iPod touch/iPhone and/or voiding the warranty.**

Comment: Possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/4668/jailbreaking-my-ipod-touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible. [blackra1n](http://blackra1n.com) from [geohot](http://iphonejtag.blogspot.com/). geohot is a former member of the iPhone Dev Team.

Answer (score 1):

According to the iPhone Dev-Team Blog:

```
iPod touch 2G

Sorry, no support at this time within PwnageTool, use Redsn0w for **an earlier (pre 3.1) firmware release instead.**
```

If you have 3.1, you cannot jailbreak. Not sure what's unclear about that.